# Convergence in measure theory

Tags: measure-theory

Let $u_n$ be a sequence converging to $u$ in $L^2$. Let $f(t)$ be a bounded continuous function. Can I say that $f(u_n)$ converges to $f(u)$ in $L^p$ for every $1<p<\infty$?

Comment: Are you working in a finite measure space?

Answer (score 2):

If $\mu(X)=\infty$ then $u\in L_2(X,\mu)$ may not imply that $f(u)\in L_p(X,\mu)$ (for any $p<\infty$). For example take $(X,\mu)=(\mathbb{R},dx), \ u(x)=e^{-x^2}, \ f(u)\equiv 1$.

If $\mu(X)<\infty$:

Assume additionally that $u_n$ converges to $u$ a.e. Then using continuity of $f$ also $f(u_n)$ converges to $f(u)$ a.e. On the other hand one has $|f(u_n)-f(u)|^p\leq (2M)^p\in L_1(X,\mu)$, where $M=\sup |f|$, so $f(u_n)$ converges to $f(u)$ in $L_p(X,\mu)$ by the Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem.

Now if $u_n$ does not converge to $u$ a.e. then first extract a subsequence $u_{n_k}$ which does (well known fact) and then reasoning as above obtain that $f(u_{n_k})$ converges to $f(u)$ in $L_p(X,\mu)$. Finally observe that the same argument gives that every subsequence of the sequence $f(u_n)$ has a further subsequence which converges in $L_p(X,\mu)$ to $f(u)$. This is enough to get that the whole sequence $f(u_n)$ converges to $f(u)$.